# How to make parent div's height scale to its children?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make it so that the message box will always be centered vertically to the X, even if more content is added into the message box. I tried wrapping the message and the X in a div called tips and setting the message div with a top: -50% but that did not seem to work. Is this a CSS or jQuery thing? I also tried adding overflow: hidden but no luck.

CSS

```
body{
    background: gray;
}

/*    Tips   */
.tooltips{
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
}

.tip-icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.tips{
    position: relative;
}

/*    Message    */
.tip-message{
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    top: -50%;
    width: 400px; 
}

.arrow-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    right: -50px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;

    border-left: 50px solid #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z7ou07rL/

Comment: Are you just trying to vertically center that element?

Comment: `.tip-icon` DIV should be child of `.tip-message` just as `.arrow-right` because other containers  have 0 in height, due to content absolutely positioned. See e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/z7ou07rL/1/  Now i'm not sure this is a solution for you

Comment: The reason it is outside is because on the X hover I want the message to display, so initially the message will have an opacity of 0

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with jQuery

```
var toolHeight = $('.tip-message').height();

$('.tip-icon').css('top', (toolHeight/2)-1);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z7ou07rL/2/